# In Python, why raise/except instead of throw/catch ? Any other language using this naming convention?

Tags: python, exception, try-catch

In Python, we use try/except to handle exceptions.

However, I have no knowledge of any other language using such naming convention.

On the other hand, I know that the following languages use try/catch and throw:

- C#
- Java
- Javascript

A search of `try except` on Google gives, on first page, only Python and a Microsoft C/C++ extension.

**Why have Python developers chosen raise/try-except instead of throw/try-catch like many other languages do?**

**In addition, does any other language use raise/try-except?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python, we can make use of this statement by using multiple *except* statements under a *try* condition, hence this can become a good programming practice.
Python was developed for an easy understand-ability of the code even by a person with no programming knowledge, this is to avoid unclear or confusing codes to understand for future review.

Comment: Hope you got this right

Comment: C also can use multiple catches. And 'raise' is just as confusing as 'throw'.

Answer (score 2):

All pascal language are also using try / except naming convention like Delphi & lazarus